# Camunda fox client - Listener startup error

Tags: java, camunda

I'm using camunda 7.0.0-Final with fox client included. When I redeloy my application I get the following error.

```
    Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class 
    com.camunda.fox.client.impl.web.ProcessArchiveServletContextListener
    at com.camunda.fox.client.impl.web.ProcessArchiveServletContextListener.contextInitialized(ProcessArchiveServletContextListener.java:28)
    at     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1655)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

REMARK: I added the following lines to the tomcat 7 logging.properties file in the conf subdirectory of the server

```
    com.camunda.fox.client.level    = DEBUG
    com.camunda.fox.client.handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

From the source code line ProcessArchiveServletContextListener.java:28 I guess that the injection of the variable

```
     @Inject
    private ProcessArchiveSupport processArchiveSupport;
```

works not like expected. Do I have to configure something to get the injection working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you mix camunda fox 6.2 Process Applications with camunda BPM 7.0 platform. This does not work. You have to migrate your Process Application as described in our [migration guide](http://docs.camunda.org/latest/guides/migration-guide/#migrate-from-camunda-fox). Then you will have a shiny working camunda BPM 7.0 application :-)

Cheers
Bernd